# How do I get a pre-signed URL to LIST a bucket's contents?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

This is the example project I am working with.
Specifically the PresignedUrlSample class.

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-dotnet][1]

The problem is this works when passing in an object key that represents a file in my bucket but does not work when passing in:

"/?prefix=PREFIX&max-keys=50"

The error is, "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

There is documentation that states this should be possible all over the place but I can not find one example on the entire internet showing how to actually create a pre-signed URL to list a bucket's contents using the ?prefix= parameter syntax.

Interesting enough if I just pass in a forward slash for the key I can list the entire bucket but obviously that is not a solution at all. The prefix parameter is what makes this viable but also causes a problem in the Amazon Signature 4 C# example project.

This is the documentation I found which explicitly states you can create pre-signed URLs to list a bucket in whole or in part. So the question is why does it not calculate a proper signature?

```
GET /?prefix=photos&max-keys=50&marker=puppy HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:42:41 +0000

Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:
htDYFYduRNen8P9ZfE/s9SuKy0U=
```

Please note that I had to modify the example because the developers hardcoded the url to use a "?" for the first "amz-" parameter but because ?prefix= already uses a question mark to parameterize the URL I had to change the Amazon query authentication parameters to all use ampersands.

Thanks to anyone who wants to dig into this stump the professor issue!

**UPDATE: Here is my solution.**
//This is from the example project PresignedUrlSample.cs class

First add 2 new parameters to the Run() static method in the class above. One will be the prefix value and the other will be max-keys value.

```
queryParams.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", AWS4SignerBase.X_Amz_Expires, HttpHelpers.UrlEncode(period.ToString()));
```

//Below this line add the following 2 lines of code.

// I added these two lines of code to the example project linked to at the top of this post. Just pass the MyPrefix and MaxKeys value and you are good to go

```
   queryParams.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "&prefix", MyPrefix);
    queryParams.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "&max-keys", MaxKeys);
```

I hope this helps someone as it drove me nuts for a full day and the solution is really quite simple once I understood the problem by debugging their code. It is not even necessary to read the dense Amazon Signature 4 documentation unless that's your bag. :D

Comment: *Please note that I had to modify the example* ... can you clarify this point?  Also, maybe, include the exact code you're using?  I suspect there's a solution, thought I can't yet say what it might be, since I write all my own code (no sdk) talking directly to the REST interface... for many reasons, not the least of which is the problem of trying to figure out what the sdk might expect you to pass in certain cases in order to get the right result.

Comment: Figured it out for anyone who might run into the same problem. The trick is not to pass in the ?prefix=<prefix> in the example project where it expects a key. Instead create 2 new parameters. sPrefix and sMaxKeys. Then simply add these parameters to the parameter collection in the example. This worked like a charm.